# Which type of protein supplement is better suited to promote skin healing?

Tags: dermatology, scar-tissue-scars, proteins, self-healing-repairing, wound

Typically, protein is used as a sport nutrition for muscle growth. But I need it for another reason. I was injured (lacerated skin wound). Physicians sometimes recommend to consume protein to promote skin healing.

But there are many different protein supplements. They are also different types of protein:

- whey protein
- multicomponent protein
- casein protein
- isolate protein
- protein hydrolysate

---

Which of the different types of protein supplements are better suited to promote optimal healing of the skin after a lacerated wound rather than using them for muscle growth?

Answer (score -1):

There are many natural things that are great for healing the skin that you should look into. I know many people who use a [dermaroller](https://www.mapleholistics.com/blog/what-is-a-dermaroller-and-what-are-its-benefits/) but you can be in a different situation because of your skin or using essential oils on your skin but don't use too much.

You should probably ask a dermatologist because they can take a look at your skin and give you the best answer. Without seeing your skin nobody can give a definitive answer.

Comment: Welcome to HealthSE, Dale! Please take the [tour](https://health.stackexchange.com/tour) and read the [help](https://health.stackexchange.com/help). We require answers to be backed up with [reliable references](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/q/783/11231).